# android how to run alerts to explain the activity components?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i need to run a list of pop ups (alerts) one after one to explain each component of my activity to the user when first run the activity. So after running the activity, user can see :

1. first alert which shoot at one view in the activity and explain the purpose of it(like a view hint).
2. after clicking OK on first alert, a second one appears and shoot on another view to explain the purpose of it.

3...same as 2

is there a library to make this work?

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/tag/198?sort=created

Answer (score 0):

Soulds like android has built in feature. It is the main activity + properly assigned navigation component (nav_graph) supported with simple fragments which describe your application.

You fire them up from main activity or you redirect the user to another/main activity when he cancels the play with hints.

I feel no need for additional libraries here, the crude examples of this behavior are made with android studio itself. Simple next/prev navigation component logic.